# HM10 BLE 4.0 Chip limit for number of discovered nearby devices

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I am working with HM10 BLE chip with Arduino. I am  able to establish serial communication between the two. In the manufacturer manual from jnhuamao.cn, it says that for AT+DISC? , "...Before V535 max results is 6, Since V535 not limit"
AT+DISC? is the AT command for scanning nearby BLE devices. The firmware for my chips are V539 and V540.

However, I am only able only received maximum 6 devices as scan result in the serial monitor. And they are different everytime. (I have 8 chips powered up nearby).  Has anyone ran into the same problem? What could be the problem? What might be the solutions?

THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

the number of discoverable devices for hm-10 is 6 devices in one go.
its in their datasheet.

Even im facing a similar issue.
Im looking for something that will give me upto 20 devices in the scann results.

Comment: Its the same in HM-11 ?